# Digital Signature System after Goldwasser, Micali and Rivest with null for empty message?

Tags: java, biginteger, null-pointer

Can i save The null pointer instead of an empty message as the leaf in the signature path of the GMR system?

Any hints appreciated!

Gerrit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I excluded the empty message from signing with GMR Digital Signature System.
I do not think, that a NULL Pointer gives a valid signature path/tree.

Answer (score 0):

You here tagged java,So if you want to assign null to any class variable that is possible...

Comment: Does the whole signature path become null then? That could be easily forged, right?